# how can we save a model using qiskit_machine_learning?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, machine-learning

How can we save a trained model using [Qiskit Machine Learning](https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/index.html) library?
I've built a VQC classification model and once finished, I'd like to save the different models to be loaded later.
There is a [`save_model`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.algorithms.VQC.html#qiskit.aqua.algorithms.VQC.save_model) method in Qiskit Aqua (`from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import VQC`) but for Qiskit Machine Learning (`from qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms.classifiers import VQC`) I havent found it yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Qiskit ML VQC is a lightweight sub-class of sklearn SVC that supplies the quantum kernel to the SVC. You can therefore leverage sklearns capabilities to say save/restore models see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#python-specific-serialization

Comment: Thanks Steve!, but using pickle or np.savez (as the same way as aqua uses in save_model method) does no work, but with joblib it finally does.